# Fetch utf8 data from firebird database

Tags: utf-8, firebird, firebird1.5

I have firebird database. I want to fetch data in UTF-8 charset, but it is not working.
Here is line how i make connection to firiberd: `return $connection = fbird_connect ("localhost:".$path, $username, $password,'UTF-8');`

And here is image, how data is fetched: 
[image: Not fetching UTF-8]

Where is the problem?

Comment: The character set is called `UTF8` in Firebird (without a `-`), have you checked if that parameter expects the Firebird character set name? Also, could you tag the language you are using. And finally, do the columns actually have a character set? If the character set is not specified, then they are likely are character set `NONE` which can't be converted to another character set.